# How to run a method from a class of another package in java

Tags: java, class

I am new to java ! I am sorry if the question is dumb ! Package is like this

- myapp (folder)

  - print (folder)

    - printer.java
  - main.java
  - manifest.txt

So myapp is a package that contains another package (subpackage) print.

Code in **main.java**

```
package myapp;
import myapp.print;
class app{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printer po = new printer();
        po.printthis("Worked");
    }
}
```

Code in **printer.java**

```
package myapp.print;
public class printer{
    public void printthis(String text){
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Now I cannot make it to run , the error says what is printer word in main.java.
What I do is first compile the printer.java and then compile main.java but while compiling main.java the error comes up and it cannot be compiled.I am using **CLI**, Please help.

Comment: You don't need to have multiple packages.  While there are likely multiple problems with your code, the `import` statement is wrong and you may not have to even use an import if the class be in the same package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the code like this

```
import myapp.print.printer;
```

in your main.java class. Or you can import all files from `print` package like this:

```
import myapp.print.*;
```

I also recommend you to read about [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid statement:

```
import myapp.print;
```

You need to import either the specific class or the whole package with the `.*` wildcard:

```
import myapp.print.printer; // just imports the printer class
import myapp.print.*;       // imports everything under the myapp.print package
```

Comment: @WaqasTahir Have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Answer (score 1):

Read Documentation first,
**stackoverflow** is not a tutorial

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

by the way 
import whole package or specific class

```
import myapp.print.printer;
import myapp.print.*;
```